# Mis-setting django's ALLOWED_HOSTS setting does not give understandable errors

Tags: python, django, http, debugging

Django's [ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) setting, if set to a different host than the browser is connecting to, simply causes a 400, with no indication of the problem.

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com']
```

If you hit django by connecting straight to the IP, rather than through example.com, you get a plain 400 page.

This only happens (as documented) with `DEBUG = FALSE`, but it happens through wsgi and through manage.py.

**This has taken me far longer than I care to admit to debug.**

Where is the debug output that could have saved me from this vague error? Shouldn't at least manage.py's output give a hint?

The page simply says `400 Bad Request` and the log is:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [23/Oct/2014 11:33:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 26
```

Comment: I would suggest you configure your Django project to send you emails each time an exception is thrown. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Django error logs.

```
[ERROR] [2014-10-23 12:46:06,073] [base 6808 140062533326784] [Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'whatver.host'.You may need to add u'whatever_host' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.]
```

Here's an example log config. you should be logging Djanogo errors if you hope to debug anything.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'error_file': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filename': os.path.join(LOG_PATH, 'error.log'),
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'maxBytes': 1 * 1024 * 1024,
            'backupCount': 2
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['error_file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My log (see updated question) does not say that, this is from a vanilla django install

Comment: It will log them to stdout when using runserver - but presumably you never had this problem using runserver because DEBUG would be True. you'd need to configure a logger to capture this information when running elsewhere.

Comment: It did not output this log when DEBUG is off, even with runserver, fyi.

Comment: Confirmed this log config logs the error properly, with manage.py and with wsgi. Thank you so much, I always assumed the log output was simply the normal access log output that manage.py gives you!